# Error using predict with klaR package, NaiveBayes

Tags: r, bayesian, predict

I'm using the `klaR` package's `predict` method as mentioned in the post [Naive bayes in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157626/naive-bayes-in-r):

```
nb_testpred <- predict(mynb, newdata=testdata).
```

`nb_testpred` is my Naive Bayes model, developed on `traindata`; `testdata` is the remaining data.

However, I get this error:

```
Error in FUN(1:10[[4L]], ...) : subscript out of bounds
```

I'm not sure what's going on - `testdata` has fewer rows than `traindata`, and the same number of columns.

For reference, my code looks like this:

```
ind       <- sample(2, nrow(mydata), replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.9,0.1))
traindata <- mydata[ind==1,]
testdata  <- mydata[ind==2,]
myformula <- as.factor(dep) ~ X1 + as.factor(X2) + as.factor(X3) + as.factor(X4) + X5 + as.factor(X6) + as.factor(date) + as.factor(hour)
mynb        <- NaiveBayes(myformula, data=traindata)
nb_testpred <- predict(mynb, newdata=testdata) #where I'm getting an error...
```

A sample of the data is here (the original file has 100,000+ rows):

```
sampledata <- structure(list(dep = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), X1 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), X2 = c(200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L), X3 = structure(c(4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c(".", "1400000", "2400000", "900000"), class = "factor"), X4 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 0L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 0L), X5 = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), X6 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L),     date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("9/23/2012", 
"9/24/2012"), class = "factor"), hour = c(18L, 17L, 23L, 8L, 1L, 19L, 19L, 16L, 22L, 2L, 12L, 16L, 15L, 9L, 1L, 9L, 
13L, 19L)), .Names = c("dep", "X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6", "date", "hour"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you try producing a reproducible example using `dput(mydata)`? (if your data is too large, select only a few rows, and see if the same error occurs, then provide that shortened data).

Comment: Or you can simulate some data and share that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You can act as follows:

```
traindata$dep=factor(traindata$dep)
mynb <- NaiveBayes(dep~.,traindata)
```

Then it works, however you should refine your data to have avoid constant columns.